# install Visual Studio WEB Express not install SQL server

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to install Visual Studio .NET WEB Express, I am forced to install SQL Server Express. but I have SQL Server Professional installed in my computer. how to get rid of this in its installation ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling SQL Server Express from the list of installed programs in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, you have to install it. But you can remove it after. You will have two instances of SQL Server on your host (by default MSSQLSERVER and SQLEXPRESS).